# writing a brief description of yourself

Tags: writing, cv, job, biology

I have just started my first job in a company as an engineer, I was asked to write a brief description of myself which will be sent to all the staffs. 
Could you please provide some template? how we can write an interesting autobiography?

edited: Having said that some humor or random facts can be included in this bio.

Comment: Is that a challenge get "interesting" and "engineer" in the same sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend asking whoever is asking you to do this for a past example. Different institutions have vastly different styles -- e.g. some places might be OK with including some humor or random facts in your bio, whereas other places are all business.

That said, you can always get some generic examples by googling "bio examples".

(Also, since this is a workplace question, it's probably more appropriate for https://workplace.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand to make it short with only a few sentences. You should mention relevant academic steps and/or relevant experiences. You can also add achievements, random facts, humor and hobbies. The style should reflect your personality or how you want to be percieved by the other staffs.
A good example should be provided by the top executives of your company and the information should be available on the website of the company and could be used as a template.
I agree with ekl that considering the culture of the workplace/company is important for the style/format of the description.

Comment: some humor or random facts can be included in this bio.